# Re Initialization express Application

Tags: node.js, express

I have node.js application, which was built on express.js framework.

```
const app = express();
require('./config')(app);
require('./services')(app);
```

./config/config.js we instantiate config:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
   const conf = {APIKey: 1234567890, url: '<someurl>'};
   app.set('config', conf);
};
```

./services/APIService.js we create service instance(singleton)

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  app.set('apiService', new APIService(app));
};

function APIService(app) {
   const config = app.get('config');
   this.key = config.APIKey;
};

APIService.prototype.sendRequest = () => {
   const config = app.get('config');
   this._send(config.url, 'some text');
};
```

**Or, service2**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
   const config = app.get('config');
   const myMod = require('myMod')(config.APIKey);
}
```

Cool, all works correct. But sometime administrator will change some config data. So, we create new config, set him to

```
newConf = {APIKey: 1234000000, url: '<some_new_url>'};
app.set('config', newConf);
```

*APIService.sendRequest*, will send request to CHANGED url, but *APIService.key* still unchanged. And *myMod* already instantiated with old config data.

We need write some setter methods, like this

```
//for APIService
APIService.prototype.setConfig = () => {
   const config = app.get('config');
   this.key = config.APIKey;
};

//for service 2
/* change const myMod to let myMod and create method for overriding */
```

or *bang!* kill and restart node.js server process. Bad idea. Maybe exist some method for this goal, something like **app.restart()** for safely reinitializing application(or, maybe, his parts)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call `app.set('apiService', new APIService(app));` again ? or just have getter and setter on the prototype for your params.

Better way should be to have a new APIService object at each new request with a middleware, somehting like :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next){
   req.api = new APIService(app);
   next();
});
```

And use req.api.

Comment: Yes, seems like I need override all entities with new config values(or creating setters for every of dependencies). But, IMHO, its not better way and I looking for more elegant approach, maybe via native express methods

Comment: Express is all about middleware http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html (like my example code)